# adding a console target to GDM

Tags: login, console, gdm

In KDM, KDE's display manager, there's an option to exit the DM and login at the terminal.  Gnome's display manager does not have this option.

Here's the entry for Cinnamon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cinnamon
Comment=This session logs you into Cinnamon
Exec=cinnamon-session-cinnamon
TryExec=/usr/bin/cinnamon
Icon=
Type=Application
```

I think it should be easy enough to create a console entry, but what would or should I place in the `Exec` or `TryExec` fields of the entry?

I tried to google for how to do this, but this is all I [got](http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/add_console_login_option_to_gdm-4639970/): but the post listed has no answers.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I tried checking to see if there was a dedicated file for KDM where the console fall-back session mode was defined, but I didn't find any.

Comment: To get to a Console its easier to remove GDM from the runlevel and use `startx`

Comment: You should be able to get into a tty with ctrl-alt-f[1-6] from GDM. Not absolutely sure though, I don't use gnome.

Comment: @eyoung100 @Cthulhu-tentacles yes, I know.  I'm well aware of both `startx` and `ttys`.  The whole point is that I don't want to have to do either of those.  I want to be able to login via the console _through a_ ___GDM entry___.

Comment: You cant, as logging in to a true console requires stopping GDM.  If you mean a virtual terminal like gnome-terminal tat is doable.

Comment: How does KDM, do it then?  I figured that if KDM is capable of letting the user easily exit the X Server completely and login via their hardware terminal, then why can't GDM do likewise?  The whole goal is to exit the X Server from within GDM so that I can login at the terminal.

Comment: Because Desktop Switching doesn't involve Killing the X Server, only the session inside the X Server.  Most users leave the session running and do as tentecales suggests, or like i suggested.

Comment: @eyoung100 Under many Unix variants including Linux, logging in to a text console does not require stopping X, because the OS provides multiple virtual consoles. The display manager can switch to a different text console and run a shell as the user on that console.

Comment: @Gilles Then I'm all ears...

Comment: @eyoung100 Try running this from a root shell inside an X session under Linux: `c=$(fgconsole); d=$(openvt -vswl su - gilles 2>&1); chvt $c; deallocvt ${d##*[^0-9]}` (see the man pages to find out what each command does). I don't know how to get GDM to do that.